# Valid XHTML: Document type does not allow element "p"; missing one of "object"

Tags: xhtml

I am trying to validate my document as XHTML 1.0 Transitional (W3C). I have the following error:

Line 322, Column 3: document type does not allow element "p" here; missing one of "object", "applet", "map", "iframe", "button", "ins", "del" start-tag

Which corresponds to this code: `<p><strong>Q: How much?</strong></p>`

```
<h2>Top Four Questions</h2>
<p><a name="tf1" id="tf1"></a>
<p><strong>Q: How much?</strong></p>
<p>We look forward to hearing from you!</p>
</div>
```

How can this be solved?

Thanks!

Comment: And what is the parent element of the `p`? That is the actual issue.

Comment: You are missing a closing `<p>` tag.  You have 4 opening `<p>` tags but only 3 closing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<h2>Top Four Questions</h2>
<p><a name="tf1" id="tf1"></a>
<p><strong>Q: How much?</strong></p>
<p>We look forward to hearing from you!</p>
</div>
```

should be

```
<h2>Top Four Questions</h2>
<p><a name="tf1" id="tf1"></a></p>
<p><strong>Q: How much?</strong></p>
<p>We look forward to hearing from you!</p>
```

You can't use a paragraph element within a paragraph element. That's why you get a validation error. So close the `p` tag on the second line.